# Why does the compiler store using s0 and a0 instead of sp?

Tags: riscv

This is a segment of a program that I compiled.

```
func:                              
        addi    sp, sp, -32
        sd      ra, 24(sp)
        sd      s0, 16(sp)
        addi    s0, sp, 32
        sd      a0, -24(s0)
        ld      a0, -24(s0)
        ld      a0, 0(a0)
        lb      a0, 0(a0)
        sb      a0, -25(s0)
        jal     x0,  LBB0_1
```

I don't understand the lines:

```
        sd      a0, -24(s0)
        ld      a0, -24(s0)
        ld      a0, 0(a0)
        lb      a0, 0(a0)
```

Why does it use s0 for the first two instructions and then a0 for the next two instead of using sp like it did earlier. Is there a way to write it so it doesn't use s0/a0 and uses just sp?

Answer (score 1):

**s0 is the frame pointer**. You have probably these two "useless" instructions ld/st with s0 because you are compiling without optimization (those two instructions could be deleted). The two ld instructions using a0 are however depending on your code and are dependent to the first argument of the function func.

Comment: Did you find my answer helpful, or do you need more help?